# Freemarker Performance

Tags: performance, struts2, freemarker

Hi i have a legacy program which uses struts 2.0.11 with spring 2 and using freemarker 2.4.23 as the template engine.

My `struts.properties` are as follows:

```
struts.freemarker.wrapper.altMap=true
struts.freemarker.mru.max.strong.size =250
struts.freemarker.beanwrapperCache=true
struts.freemarker.templatesCache=true
struts.freemarker.templatesCache.updateDelay=600000
```

We notice that there is always a delay of a few seconds when the last line of our jsp content is processed. For example, this is an extract from our log:

> [6/12/16 15:41:42:253 SGT] 0000014b SystemOut     O [12/6/2016 15:41:42] INFO [WebContainer : 5]  | End Session:2016-06-12 15:41:42.252
>
> [6/12/16 15:41:44:794 SGT] 0000014b TimerIntercep I com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor doLog Executed action [/!execute] took 4195 ms.

I am still not sure what causes the 2 second delay. Can any experts on freemarker explain this?

Part of the thread dump

```
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade.getRealPath(ServletContextFacade.java:243)
    at freemarker.cache.WebappTemplateLoader.findTemplateSource(WebappTemplateLoader.java:103)
    at freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader.findTemplateSource(MultiTemplateLoader.java:73)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.findTemplateSource(TemplateCache.java:788)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.lookupTemplateWithAcquisitionStrategy(TemplateCache.java:748)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.access$500(TemplateCache.java:58)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache$TemplateCacheTemplateLookupContext.lookupWithAcquisitionStrategy(TemplateCache.java:914)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache$TemplateCacheTemplateLookupContext.lookupWithLocalizedThenAcquisitionStrategy(TemplateCache.java:934)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateLookupStrategy$Default020300.lookup(TemplateLookupStrategy.java:105)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.lookupTemplate(TemplateCache.java:736)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplateInternal(TemplateCache.java:372)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:291)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2383)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:2478)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:162)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:326)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:332)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:2505)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:171)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:326)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:332)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:305)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:384)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:530)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:43)
    at com.ibm._jsp._generalenquirysearch._jspx_meth_s_select_0(_generalenquirysearch.java:3500)
    at com.ibm._jsp._generalenquirysearch._jspx_meth_s_form_0(_generalenquirysearch.java:7904)
    at com.ibm._jsp._generalenquirysearch._jspService(_generalenquirysearch.java:806)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
```

Comment: It's not a freemarker problem

Comment: Why do you suspect that it's related to FreeMarker? Especially because you are talking about JSP above.

Comment: We are suspecting because we uses freemarker template to display the content. On the above I put in system out in our .jsp to display out the current processing time in our footer.jsp which is the last include file of our decorated template. So I m suspecting could it be because of the freemarker that causes this delay ?